# Eclipse-like behavior in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

Is there something to make Visual Studio act a bit like Eclipse in default configuration? Eclipse keybindings would please me at least, I have searched the web but everything I found was about going in the opposite direction - to make Eclipse behave like VS, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It's a huge refactoring plugin. You can set the keybindings as you want in it. There are three default bindings - VS style, IntelliJ style and one more, don't remember what.